# Why does window.scrollTo() work in chrome on my react site but not in Firefox?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, scroll, single-page-application

I have a React website here: [www.assertivesolutions.ca](http://www.assertivesolutions.ca).

If you visit the site in Chrome and scroll down to the "What We Do" section and click on the "Our Services" button, you get taken to the Our Services page. Notice is starts further down on the page and scrolls up to the top. This is because, as an SPA, it doesn't really go to a different page; it stays on the same page and just changes the content. So if you're scrolled half way down the page before you click the button, it will still be half way down the page after you click the button. So I implemented a fix to scroll to the top in the componentDidMount() hook:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

However, if you try the same thing in Firefox, it does not work. It stays scrolled half way down the page.

So I can take two approaches to solving this:

1. Figure out how to get scrolling to work in Firefox.
2. Figure out a different way of making sure the Services page loads at the top other than using `window.scrollTo(0,0)`.

I'm leaning towards 2) because I have to imagine there must be a way in SPA websites to accomplish what I want.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish either 1) or 2) (preferably 2).